# Passing the results from findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock into a variable

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to pass the result from the query into the variable array

```
var petitions = [PFObject] = []
```

Then return that result. How I can do that in **Swift**?

```
func getPetitions(employeeId: String, employeeBusiness: String) -> [PFObject] {

    var petitions: [PFObject] = []

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Petitions")
    query.selectKeys(["petitionDate", "availableFrom", "availableTo"])
    query.whereKey("employeeId", equalTo:employeeId)
    query.whereKey("employeeBusiness", equalTo:employeeBusiness)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                NSLog("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) petitions.")
                for object in objects {
                    petitions.append(object)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return petitions
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The query is ansynchronusly passed which means `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` might not (99% won't) be finished when you return your `petitions`.

You can do your stuff which you want to do directly in the function:

```
var petitions: [PFObject] = [] //class variable

func getPetitions(employeeId: String, employeeBusiness: String) {

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Petitions")
    query.selectKeys(["petitionDate", "availableFrom", "availableTo"])
    query.whereKey("employeeId", equalTo:employeeId)
    query.whereKey("employeeBusiness", equalTo:employeeBusiness)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                NSLog("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) petitions.")
                for object in objects {
                    self.petitions.append(object)
                }
                // update UI
                // or just do whatever you want with the petitions.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can write a block function:

```
func getPetitions(employeeId: String, employeeBusiness: String, block:PFArrayResultBlock) {

        var query = PFQuery(className:"Petitions")
        query.selectKeys(["petitionDate", "availableFrom", "availableTo"])
        query.whereKey("employeeId", equalTo:employeeId)
        query.whereKey("employeeBusiness", equalTo:employeeBusiness)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(block)
        }
    }
```

To call it:

```
getPetitions("employeeId", "employeeBusiness", block: {
    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            // do whatever you want with your objects..
            // update UI
            // or just do whatever you want with the petitions.
})
```

Another way to solve this, is to make the query synchronusly:

```
func getPetitions(employeeId: String, employeeBusiness: String) -> [PFObject] {
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Petitions")
    query.selectKeys(["petitionDate", "availableFrom", "availableTo"])
    query.whereKey("employeeId", equalTo:employeeId)
    query.whereKey("employeeBusiness", equalTo:employeeBusiness)
    var objects = query.findObjects()
    if let petititons = objects as? [PFObject] {
        return petititons
    } else {
        return [PFObject]() // return an empty pf object array. If you want, return nil.. but the return value must be [PFObject]? if you do this.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand completion blocks. You can't return a result from an async call like this. Instead you need to make the function a void (no result) and then put the code that deals with the result in your completion block.

You should refactor your `getPetitions` method to take it's own completion block as a parameter. Once the async Parse call is done and you're code to append the items is done, you'd then invoke the provided block.

Comment: Can you show me an example please? Thanks in advance